# Проблема с include

Tags: apache, include, php, ubuntu

Добрый день,

На проекте используем Yii. Недавно заметили, что на сервере (проект не в продакшене) стало выдавать ошибку:

```
include(BsHtml.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory, ссылаясь на файл - /var/www/site/framework/YiiBase.php(427).
```

На локалхосте, где виндоус и uniform server все ок работает. Возможно, кто-то может что-нибудь сходу подсказать? Спасибо.

Лично я думаю, что проблема в апаче. Используем на сервере ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

Сходу - проверьте регистр имени файла.
Еще момент - убедитесь последовательно в каком-нибуь файле test.php, расположенном рядом с индексом, что данный путь точно доступен, а если недоступен - по какой причине.

Answer (score 1):

вам не нужно указывать такой путь /var/www/site/framework/YiiBase.php. Насколько я понял ваш сайт находиться в папке site. Значит вам нужно указать такой путь в инклуде framework/YiiBase.php (это если ваш инклуд в папке site).
ИЛИ 
Вы неправильно указали путь к файлу
а так же я заметил что разные имена у инклуда и у ошыбки проверте все ли имена правильные